# How long can it take to 'repair' a room?

Tags: fallout-shelter

Normally after a room is done burning it just cleans itself up, but this power room has been sooty for quite a while now, like hours. It also did not seem to perform as well as it had (which is why it is empty). The lab right below it? Burned 20s before this screen shot was taken.

Do the rooms have so many times they can be trounced before they stay ... trounced?

[image: Power room fire was hours ago, lab below it was burning 20s before this.]

Comment: I feel the burn marks are simply cosmetic and do not otherwise affect gameplay.  I have not noticed that the room gets "damaged".

Answer (score 2):

Well this appears to be a bug not a game mechanic I stumbled into.. I reloaded my vault and the room is now crisp and clean!.

Answer (score 0):

Well Normally this should happen directly after the fire is out out.

If you let the room burn down with no one inside you need to put a dweller in to instantly repair it.

Comment: not sure that's the thing - if I remember correctly, the rooms are becoming clean instantly even without any dwellers inside, but I might be wrong about that.